# Android implements the example process of mono?

Tags: android, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.android

Java implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener how these processes can not find easily while the mono? Thank you in advance ...

```
public class MyClass implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
        default:

            break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

How do I make this process a mono?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A literal translation of that sample to C# and Mono for Android would look like this:

```
public class MyClass : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
    }
}
```

While it is still possible to write your apps this way, following the Java conventions, there are nicer ways to do it in Mono for Android. In most cases where Java uses listener interfaces, Mono for Android will actually provide an event you can handle, which is much easier to use (and more C#-friendly). In this example you'd want to handle the [`Touch`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=E:Android.Views.View.Touch) and [`Click`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=E:Android.Views.View.Click) events on a view:

```
view.Touch += (sender, args) =>
              {
                  switch (args.Event.Action)
                  {
                      case MotionEventActions.Down:
                          break;
                      case MotionEventActions.Up:
                          break;
                      default:
                          break;
                  }
              };
view.Click += (sender, args) =>
              {
              };
```